# Inserting a note from a range of cells using a script

Tags: google-sheets

I was hoping the following code would take all the text values in column B and places them as a note in the corresponding row in column A.

But it doesn't.

It takes the first text value in cell B2 and inserts the same note in all the rows in column A.

How do I amend the code so that B2 text becomes a note for A2, B3 text becomes a note for A3, B4 becomes a note for A4 etc, etc.

```
function addNote() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("SKU_INFO_ASC");
  var targetCell = srcSheet.getRange("A2:A100");
  var sourceCell = srcSheet.getRange("B2:B100");

  var noteText = sourceCell.getValue();

  targetCell.setNote(noteText);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

The main problem in your code is that you are using the methods to read and write in single cells ([getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) instead of [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) and [setNote](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotenote) instead of [setNotes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotesnotes).

Try the following approach:

### Code

```
function addNote() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SKU_INFO_ASC");
  var values = sheet.getRange("A2:A100").getValues()
  sheet.getRange("B2:B100").setNotes(values)
}
```

### References

- [Range: setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Range: setNotes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnotesnotes)